# How can I strip a leading zero from an expression rendered by plotmath?

Tags: r, plotmath

Due to a journal's requirements, I need to format p values as capital, italic *P* and the values themselves without leading zero, for example, *P* = .01. I would like to include some p value labels in plots of mine.

My trouble is that I need to use [`plotmath` expressions](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/grDevices/html/plotmath.html) in order to render an italic *P* (as far as I know) but `plotmath` always renders the value with a leading zero even if I enter a string without it. As an example

```r
ggplot2::ggplot(data.frame(x = 1, y = 1)) +
  ggplot2::geom_text(x = 1, y = 1, label = "italic(P) == .01", parse = TRUE)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-05-03 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v1.0.0)</sup>

Does anyone know a solution to this problem? I guess either removing the leading zero with `plotmath` or italicizing the *P* without `plotmath` are possible options.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way would be to use the number as string.

```
ggplot2::ggplot(data.frame(x = 1, y = 1)) +
  ggplot2::geom_text(x = 1, y = 1, label = "italic(P) == '.01'", parse = TRUE)
```

[image]